# Execute a value twice from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a strange problem, I am working on a personal project in Laravel, a "Q&A" type site, so far everything is fine. When I want to post a question from the database, it will be displayed twice on the display page, even if I only put the question with a certain id.
[the error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1CbV.png)

Route:

```
Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');
```

Controllerr:

```
 public function viewUserQuestion() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();
        return view('viewQuestion', compact('posts'));
    }
    else {
        return redirect('register');
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="mailbox-read-info">
    <h5 align="center"> {{ $post->title }}</h5>
    <h6> From userID: {{ $post->user_id }}</h6>
    <span class="mailbox-read-time" align="center">Created at: {{ $post->created_at }}</span></h6>
</div><div class="mailbox-read-message">
<p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
```

Route to the display page:

```
 <td><a href="{{ route('viewQuestion', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">{{ $post->id }}</a></td>
```

What do you think would be the exact problem? I would be grateful if you could help me, does it run twice or does it?

Comment: I don't see a problem there. There's problably two different posts in your database. Are posts == questions?

Comment: Not a really a problem. Your `viewUserQuestion()` fetches the latests Posts, not a single one. If you were to show only one post/question, there would also be no need for a `@foreach` in your blade. You also don't use the route parameter  anywhere

Comment: And how should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I want to display the data from each id, but in different pages without overlapping. As it is here, you click on a question and display it not twice.